# Under Psionic-Magic Transparency, can Wish emulate psionic powers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, psionics

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm):

> The default rule for the interaction of psionics and magic is simple: Powers interact with spells and spells interact with powers in the same way a spell or normal spell-like ability interacts with another spell or spell-like ability. This is known as psionics-magic transparency.
>
> **Psionics-Magic Transparency**
>
> Though not explicitly called out in the spell descriptions or magic item descriptions, spells, spell-like abilities, and magic items that could potentially affect psionics do affect psionics.

Can a [Wish](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wish.htm) spell emulate a psionic power?

> A wish can produce any one of the following effects.
>
> - (...)
> - Duplicate any other spell of 6th level or lower, provided the spell is not of a school prohibited to you.
> - (...)
> - Duplicate any other spell of 5th level or lower even if it’s of a prohibited school.
> - (...)

Answer (score 3):

### This will be a DM call.

As you so rightly pointed out, it is NOT called out anywhere explicitly. I've had some DM's rule that if it says it affects spells specifically, then it doesn't affect powers, and powers that call out affecting powers and not spells can't affect spells, no matter what the transparency rules otherwise might have been intended to mean.

Some stick to the letter of the text, others take a more liberal approach.

Personally, I lean towards the latter, and prefer to consider it from a holistic angle. (For example, in one campaign I am part of, we just worked out how to allow an Erudite qualify for the Sandshaper prestige class. The Spell-to-Power Alternate Class Feature was used to ease the spells into a more psionic friendly format.)

Looking at the text of *[Reality Revision](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/realityRevision.htm)* from the SRD we can see that it practically mirrors *[Wish](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wish.htm)*.

**As such, this DM would vote to allow such a mimicry of psionic powers under the "prohibited school" clause of *Wish*.**

Comment: Reality Revision exist to do so, so Wish should not work, and Reality Revision has this line: Duplicate any other power **(but not a spell)** of 6th level or lower, such as a psychic warrior power. Makes it clear it can't to the opposite, Wish should have this line too for psionic powers, but all exception can't be mentionned.  You might allow it but everything that is outside the range of the precise list falls under the greater effects risk.